# Install PHP 5.5 on hostgator shared hosting

Tags: php, shared-hosting

New servers of [HostGator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HostGator) India are supporting PHP 5.4.36 only. I need to upgrade to PHP 5.5 manually by me. How can I do that?

Comment: You all should update your knowledge about this topic. You should accept the fact that before saying anything impossible one should rather see beyond his knowledge or skills. Many users have a shared provider that grants access to a system-wide PEAR installation. However, in many cases, it is advantageous to have a local copy of PEAR that can be used for packages that are not installed by the host provider. There are ways of installing PEAR both for users with a telnet/ssh shell access and users who only have ftp access.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. HostGator, and most other shared hosting providers, do not allow you to install software on their servers. You would need to upgrade to a [virtual private server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) (VPS) or a dedicated server where you can control the software installed.

Some providers run multiple versions of PHP allowing you to choose which one your site uses. You should ask if they offer this.

Comment: Wow. I just told you why you can't do it and you call it useless advice? Good luck. You're going to need it.

Comment: @DharmendraJadon If you [upgrade to HostGator India's VPS solutions](http://www.hostgator.in/vps-hosting.php), they will likely migrate your websites and data for you. But as John has said, aside from the VPS solution, you are restricted in your PHP version on a shared hosting environment. No amount of kicking and screaming (or calling exact and precise answers useless) will help you otherwise.

Comment: Haha, even the `shared-hosting` tag says: "Websites that are hosted on servers where many other peoples sites are hosted can have specific problems due to security concerns, **lack of control of installed libraries, no root access** etc."

Comment: @DharmendraJadon, the answer is not useless when it clearly explains why you ***cannot*** do what you want.  Your OP on the other hand... not so useful to the quality of SO.

Answer (score 0):

If HostGator India doesn't allow the switching of PHP versions, there is no way to update it "manually". If you need that version, consider switching hosting providers. You might want to contact HostGator support and check with them first - they may make an exception, but it's unlikely.